# Draw a image in the StatusBar not working in XE7 version

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe7

My application will display some informations in the statusbar on initialization.
I'm displaying this by drawing icons (on and off) on statusbar.
The following code works fine in Embarcadero XE3, but not work anymore in XE7 version.
The code does not raise any exception or errors.
How can I fix this?

```
procedure TFormMain.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  case Panel.Index of
    3:
    begin
      i := ICON_DATABASE_OFF;
      if HasDatabaseConnection() then
        i := ICON_DATABASE;
      ImageList1.Draw(StatusBar.Canvas, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, i);
    end;
    4:
    begin
      i := ICON_GLOBE_OFF;
      if HasInternetConnection() then
        i := ICON_GLOBE;
      ImageList1.Draw(StatusBar.Canvas, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, i);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In XE3:
[image]

**UPDATE**
(See the the comments)
The error occurs because the `OnResizeEvent` of the `FormMain`.

```
procedure TFormMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //StatusBar1.Panels[0].Width := FormMain.Width - 448;
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Width := ClientWidth - 448;
end;
```

The values that are showed when I debug are the same in both versions:
In XE3:
FormMain.Width = 1400
ClientWidth = 1024

In XE7:
FormMain.Width = 1400
ClientWidth = 1024

The defined dimension are 754 for width and 515 for height.
For some unknow reason, in XE7 the icons are not drawed.
**If I resize the form after it is open, the icons are displayed correctly!**

I do not applied any skin or change style of my application. I'm using the default configurations

The statusbar will have 6 painels:
0 - to show hints (width is flexible; changes when form width change)
1 - will show the name of the current selected company (fixed width)
2 - will show the name of the current user (fixed width)
3 - will show an icon (fixed width)
4 - will show an icon (fixed width)
5 - will show the date (fixed width)

Since the painels 1~5 have fixed dimension (total = 448), I do not see reasons to recalculate in % the width of painel [0].

Again, the problem only occurs in XE7.

[image]

Comment: Do you use styles in your project (Project - Options - Application - Appearance)? What is the runtime width of your form? If it is smaller than 450, do the images appear if you increase the width so that `Panel[0]` width is positive? Please edit your question with the answers to these questions and to include the facts you mention in the comments to Ken Whites answer.

Comment: It is frustrating to find that people asking for help are too nonchalant to answer with a few simple details that would either rule out or confirm possible reasons to their problems.

Comment: Edited. Please review it.

Comment: So did you at least *try* recalculating the width of Panel[0] to see if it changed things? Or are you just rejecting it outright because you *do not see any reason to recalculate*.

Comment: Yes, I tried. And still does not work properly. Only if I resize the window after it is opened.  
Seems to me a problem in XE7 version.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the added info. Now we know that the issue is not related to a similar issue I found with vcl styles.
If you create a new, simplified project, only a form (with OnResize) and the statusbar (same panels and images) in XE3 and then make a copy of it and compile with XE7, will it behave erroneously?

Comment: No. It's works correctly!  
Anyway, I will change my code for new version and move forward.  
Thank you all guys for help me investigate this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `TPanel.Style` to `psOwnerDraw` rather than the default `psText`. If you don't do so, `OnDrawPanel` is not called.

A quick test of similar code shows that it works (at least in XE8):

```
procedure TForm1.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel;
  const Rect: TRect);
begin
  if Panel.Index = 0 then
    ImageList1.Draw(StatusBar.Canvas, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, 0);
end;
```

The results:

[image: Statusbar image]

Based on comments by the poster (below this answer), it appears that the issue is actually related to code in the form's `OnResize` event, where there is no longer sufficient space for the two problem panels. The code in question (taken from the poster's comments):

```
procedure TFormMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Width := FormMain.Width - 448 ; 
end;
```

First, to highlight the most significant issue in the code: **Never** use `Form.Width` inside that form's event handlers! Use `Self.Width` (or simply `Width`, which implies `Self`) instead, making the correct code

```
StatusBar1.Panels[0].Width := Self.Width - 448;
```

(It would so be better to use `Self.ClientWidth`, which is the inner (client) area of the form after the resize (edge) borders and any scroll bars are removed, rather than `Width`, BTW.)

The issue with the panel drawing I think is related to the panel width calculation. If there is not enough room for the panel after sizing `Panels[0]`, then panels at index 3 and 4 become too small, and the image drawn into the rectangle isn't seen. I can reproduce this by adding this event handler to my first code block and running the app again, resizing the form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StatusBar1.Panels[1].Width := Self.Width - 448;
end;
```

Note the change in the appearance of the second panel (Panels[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m41v6.png)) in the two images below - the first is when the form is initially displayed with the designed width of 800, the second after reducing the window to 600 pixels width at runtime.

Form at 800 pixels width - note status bar panel with date:

[image]

Form at 600 pixels width - note status bar panel with date is missing

[image]

The solution here would be to first deduct the width of panels 3 and 4, and then allocate a percentage of the remaining space to panel 0. Note that I'm using the form's `ClientWidth` rather than `Width` here.

```
procedure TFormMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  Available: Double;
begin
  Available := ClientWidth - StatusBar1.Panels[3].Width -
               StatusBar1.Panels[4].Width;
  // Allocate 80% of remaining width to first panel
  StatusBar1.Panels[0] := Trunc(Available * 0.8);
end;
```

Comment: The style is set to psOwnerDraw, but still don't work. 
As I said, works fine in XE3, but not in XE7.
I do not changed the code.

Comment: It works perfectly with the code above (which I tested before posting). Put a breakpoint in your `StatusBar1DrawPanel` handler (on the `case` line) and run. What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: Nothing. I realized that, in following of the execution, OnFormResize is called with the follow code :
`procedure TFormMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject); begin StatusBar1.Panels [ 0] .Width : = FormMain.Width - 448 ; end;` 
If I comment this line, the icons are drawed correctly. Now the questions are: Why change the width of the panel will stop work and works correctly in XE3 and not in XE7?

Comment: @rodrigopandini: I don't know. I can add the same code (adjusted for my StatusBar1) to the form above, and it correctly draws. (I added exactly:  `StatusBar1.Panels[1].Width := ClientWidth - 448;` for testing.) Note: Don't use `FormMain` inside event handlers of `FormMain` - use `Self`. IOW, your code should be `StatusBar1.Panels[0].Width := Self.Width - 448;` instead. *Never* refer to a form's instance variable from within the form's event handler.

Comment: @rodrigopandini: I'm suspecting that what's happening is that there isn't enough room for the panels after `FormMain.Width - 488` is taken up by `Panels[0]` in the `OnResize`. Calculate `Panel[0].Width` as a percentage after deducting the width of panels 3 & 4 instead, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Self.Width is the wrong dimension. That includes the borders.

Comment: @David: That's simply removing the poster's reference to `FormMain`. The original code had `FormMain.Width`, and I changed it to `Self.Width`. I have no idea whether the poster wanted to include margins or not. It's not my code, and not in my answer. If you're going to nitpick, please at least make it relevant to something.

Comment: `Self.Width` appears multiple times in the answer. I think it's relevant. Your use of `ClientWidth` is sound, but there was no explanation.

Comment: @David: If you had a suggestion that I explain my use of `ClientWidth`, you should make that suggestion instead of nitpicking `Self.Width`. (The two times it is used in my post are both the OP's code; one directly from the original question, and once from my use of code use in a problem description in a comment by the OP. Neither was my code, and both were used for reference purposes only.)